# closedir() in c is giving "double free or corruption (!prev) Aborted" error

Tags: c

```
else if (S_ISDIR(file.st_mode)) { //if  is directory
   dir = opendir(argv[2]);
   if (dir == NULL) { //if invalid directory
     perror("Not a valid directory");
     closedir (dir);
     free(newFile);
     free(filePath);
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   while ((dent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) { //loop through each file
     if(dent->d_name[0]!='.' && strncmp(dent->d_name, "wrap.", 5)!=0){ //if file doesn't start with '.' or "wrap."
       filePath = (char *) realloc(filePath, strlen(dent->d_name)+strlen(argv[2])+1);
       strncat(filePath, argv[2], strlen(argv[2])); //add directory path to file path
       strncat(filePath, "/", 1); // add slash
       strncat(filePath, dent->d_name, strlen(dent->d_name)); //add filename
       fileInputDescriptor = open(filePath,O_RDONLY);

       newFile = (char *) realloc(newFile, strlen(argv[2])+strlen(dent->d_name)+6); //newFile is name of new file

       strncat(newFile, argv[2], strlen(argv[2])); //add directory path to newFile
       strncat(newFile, "/wrap.", 6); //add /wrap.
       strncat(newFile, dent->d_name, strlen(dent->d_name)); //add file name to end

       fileOutputDescriptor = open(newFile, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666); //create file

       wrap(width, fileInputDescriptor, fileOutputDescriptor);
       *newFile = '\0';
       *filePath = '\0';
       close(fileInputDescriptor);
       close(fileOutputDescriptor);
     }
   }
   closedir(dir); //close directory
}
```

I'm writing a program that will take all the files in a directory and create new a "wrapped" version of the file in the same directory where the text in the file is formatted in a different way. The code is working, but i'm getting the error "double free or corruption (!prev) Aborted". I found out this is happening when closedir() is being called but I can't figure out why.

Comment: Your `relloc`s are out by one. You are forgetting the null terminator

Comment: Although it might be alright, a lot of this code just looks wrong. What is `*newFile = '\0'` doing in there? Just "clearing" the string at the end? Also calling `free` before you pull the ripcord on `exit` is nice and all, but it's not like it matters.

Comment: using `strlen` as the length argument defeats the purpose of `strncat`.  Also, these successive concatenations are the textbook example of a Shlemiel The Painter algorithm.

Comment: Don't call `closedir(dir)` when `opendir()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: Instead of a bunch of `strncat()` calls, use `sprintf()` to format the pathname all at once.

Comment: You need to add 1 to `strlen()` when using it as the argument to `strncat()`. Otherwise you won't copy the null terminator, and the next `strncat()` won't be able to find the end of the string. But as @ChristianGibbons said, you can just use `strcat()`.

Comment: If someone told you that `strncat()` is "safer", you misunderstood how to use it safely. The length should be the amount of space available in the destination, not the length of the source. The purpose is to ensure you don't write out of bounds.